# Unexpected number showing up at the end of JSON body

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to write a simple demo that reads a json file with php and ajax. In js I have

```
// initial entry point
function main(){
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.addEventListener("click",test);
    button.addEventListener("click",getSummary);
}

function test(){
    console.log("button was clicked");
}

function getSummary(){
    asyncRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    asyncRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", processResponse, false);
    console.log("sending request");
    asyncRequest.open("GET","http://localhost/summary.php",true);
    asyncRequest.send(null);
}

function processResponse(){
    console.log("processing request");
    if(asyncRequest.readyState==4 && asyncRequest.status==200){
        console.log(asyncRequest.response);
    }
}
```

summary.php

```
<?php
$data = readfile("summary.json");
header('Content-Type: text/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

summary.json

```
{
    "products":[
        {
            "product":"professional pencil",
            "image":"pencil.jpg",
            "description":"The most verstile tool any programmer can have. With this professional pencil you'll be able to sketch out plans and fix mistakes!"
        },
        {
            "product":"coffee mug",
            "image":"coffee_mug.jpg",
            "description":"Keep your programming skills sharp and your coffee hot with this one of a kind coffee mug."
        },
        {
            "product":"programming book",
            "image":"programming_book.jpg",
            "description":"Learn how to program effectively by reading this book."
        }
    ]
}
```

When I make a request I get an unusual `706` at the end of the response.
`curl localhost/summary.php | Select Content -Expand Content | jq` produces

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "product": "professional pencil",
      "image": "pencil.jpg",
      "description": "The most verstile tool any programmer can have. With this professional pencil you'll be able to sketch out plans and fix mistakes!"
    },
    {
      "product": "coffee mug",
      "image": "coffee_mug.jpg",
      "description": "Keep your programming skills sharp and your coffee hot with this one of a kind coffee mug."
    },
    {
      "product": "programming book",
      "image": "programming_book.jpg",
      "description": "Learn how to program effectively by reading this book."
    }
  ]
}
706
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to type one by one to see where the number is getting added?

Comment: Its normally a rogue echo added for some debugging that got left in

Comment: The `706` is what you encoded as JSON. Your variable `$data` does not contain what you think it would, and READING THE MANUAL for `readfile` will tell you why.

Comment: use `$data = file_get_contents("summary.json");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your summary.php you actually want it to be more like the following to do what you are intending to do

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("summary.json");
header('Content-Type: text/json;charset=utf-8');
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` isn't necessary when the data is already JSON text.

And, more importantly, `readFile` returns a number indicating the number of bytes read. That's the number in `$data` which you're then outputting and seeing in your results. `readFile` sends the actual file data direct to the output, not into a variable.

So your code can be shortened to simply

```
header('Content-Type: text/json;charset=utf-8');
readfile("summary.json");
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php